# Using ORM, can I map a DB table with columns a, b, c to a class with a Map with keys a, b, c?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, orm, mapping

For example, imagine we have a DB table Person like this:

```
|---------------|
|Name|Age|Height|
|---------------|
|Bob | 34|   167|
|Jane| 76|   181|
|Joe | 55|   176|
|---------------|
```

Using an ORM framework in Java (Hibernate, Spring Data JPA, etc), can I map this table to a class like this:

```
public class Person {
  private Map<String, Object> attributes;
  // No other fields!
  ..
}
```

Where e.g. first row of the table would be represented by the Person object with *attributes* field equal to:

```
{{"Name" -> "Bob"}, {"Age" -> 34}, {"Height" -> 167}}
```

If this is at all possible, how would I go about it? Many thanks!

Comment: FWIW "Spring Data JPA" is not an ORM, and just uses a real JPA implementation. In terms of your problem, if that was a join table then it could represent a Map, and the "Name" being a FK column to a Person table.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own utility that goes through the Java Properties (or getters) using reflection and build that map for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do exactly that. One option is to use [constructor expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor), to have a "view object" with attributes map, and return that from queries, but you would still have to have a normal entity mapped to db table. In that case your query would look something like this

```
select new my.package.PersonVO(p) from Person p...
```

You would only have to have a appropriate constructor in PersonVO

```
public PersonVO(Person person) {
    attributes.put("name", person.getName());
    ...
}
```